# How to just show an alert with react-error-boundary, leaving the children untouched?

Tags: reactjs, react-error-boundary

I've a `<CartIconButton>` which opens a `<VariantsDialog>` component. I've wrapped the dialog inside the `<ErrorBoundary>` component. The `trigger` prop is the actual button which opens the dialog:

```jsx
<ErrorBoundary>
  <VariantsDialog productId={product.id}
    trigger={props => <CartIconButton {...props} />} />
</ErrorBoundary>
```

The dialog itself is using `useErrorHandler()` **(1)** to signal the parent that something went wrong during it's async operation. It renders the trigger too:

```js
export const VariantsDialog = ({ productId, trigger }) => {
  const [loading, error, data] = useFetch(`/api/variats/${productId}`);
  useErrorHandler(error); // (1)

  return (
    <>
      {trigger(bindTrigger(popupState))}
      <Dialog>{/* dialog content */}</Dialog>
    </>
  );
};
```

I don't really want to replace the content inside `<ErrorBoundary>` (that is, the rendered `<CartIconButton>` should remain). I'd like to just show a notification.

Would be possibile to istruct the library to "just call this method when something bad happens, but still render the children" ?